# Unresponsive Clojure REPL after exception

Tags: exception, clojure, read-eval-print-loop, leiningen

If I start a REPL and then do something that throws an exception like `(use 'non-existent-thing)` ** then after that the REPL ceases to evaluate anything I enter. Is there a special key I can press to make it turn round, face me, uncross its arms and listen once more ? Or must I ctrl-d, restart, type everything up to where I was and get it right this time ?

which results in:

> Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate non_existent_thing__init.class or non_existent_thing.clj on classpath:  (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)

edit: I should have mentioned that I'm using lein repl

Comment: The same happens to me when I use Eclipse. I think it may be a problem with the REPL itself?

Comment: it doesn't do it the IntelliJ REPL I just discovered, so it may be Leiningen thing

Comment: Why can't you use `lein swank` with emacs?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that and I've use lein repl on Windows, Linux and OSX. The only thing that's a little strange is that I have to tap enter once or twice to the repl prompt back.

Just in case... What version of leiningen do you use? Recent JDK? Clojure version?

Comment: Leiningen 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT on Java 1.6.0_22 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Clojure 1.2.0, Ubuntu 10.04. I did lein new blank, then lein repl

Comment: Did you add `[ring/ring-devel "0.2.0"]` in your project? I think, you are missing it.

Comment: I've just tried on another machine and the problem does not occur there so it must be a problem with my lein installation...

Comment: Do you have a classpath variable set by default? I've had that interfere with running leiningen (although it could have been clojure).

Comment: just upgraded to the latest leiningen and the problem has gone, all's well that ends well.

Comment: Bill this is not a _bug_ but a **feature**. You can read it here http://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise/wiki/ReleaseNotes

Comment: I think you're referring to problem I had with leiningen referencing the classpath. Correct? IIRC, Apple had added quicktime to the classpath on my Windows machine at work. If I ran lein repl under JDK 7, it would fail because it could not find important classes, but it did not have that problem running under jdk 6. When I removed the classpath entry it would run fine under either JVM. Also, what part of the CCW repl release notes are you referring to? Its a long document.